discord.py voice recording bot in Discord problem
I've been trying to build a bot that records audio from a voice channel on discord and then upload the file to Dropbox. However, none of the methods from the internet really worked (I've tried Interactions, discord-ext-voice-recv, discord-ext-audiorec,...). Has anyone really built an audio recording Discord bot in Python & can you guide me in the right direction? Thank you!
Here's what I've got:
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user}')
    await tree.sync()

@tree.command(name="join", description="Join a voice channel")
async def join(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.user.voice:
        channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
        if interaction.guild.voice_client is not None:
            return await interaction.guild.voice_client.move_to(channel)
        await channel.connect()
        await interaction.response.send_message("Joined the voice channel")
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("You are not in a voice channel")

@tree.command(name="leave", description="Leave the voice channel")
async def leave(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.guild.voice_client:
        await interaction.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        await interaction.response.send_message("Left the voice channel")
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("I'm not in a voice channel")

@tree.command(name="record", description="Start recording")
async def start_record(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.guild.voice_client:
        interaction.guild.voice_client.start_recording(discord.sinks.MP3Sink(), finished_callback, interaction)
        await interaction.response.send_message("Recording...")
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("I'm not in a voice channel")

async def finished_callback(sink, interaction):
    recorded_users = [f"<@{user_id}>" for user_id in sink.audio_data]
    files = [discord.File(audio.file, f"{user_id}.mp3") for user_id, audio in sink.audio_data.items()]
    for file in files:
        save_and_upload_recording(file.fp.read(), file.filename)
    await interaction.channel.send(f"Finished! Recorded audio for {', '.join(recorded_users)}.", files=files)

@tree.command(name="stop", description="Stop recording and transcribe audio")
async def stop_recording(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.guild.voice_client:
        interaction.guild.voice_client.stop_recording()
        await interaction.response.send_message("Stopped!")
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("I'm not recording")

def save_and_upload_recording(wav_bytes, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(wav_bytes)
    upload_to_dropbox(file_name)
    os.remove(file_name)
    return file_name

def upload_to_dropbox(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
        dbx.files_upload(f.read(), f'/{file_name}', mute=True)
    print(f'Uploaded {file_name} to Dropbox')

def transcribe_audio(file_name):
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(file_name)
    audio.export(file_name, format="wav")
    with sr.AudioFile(file_name) as source:
        audio_data = recognizer.record(source)
        try:
            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio_data)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            text = "[Could not understand audio]"
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            text = f"[Could not request results; {e}]"
    return text

@tree.command(name="list_recordings", description="List all recordings")
async def list_recordings(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    entries = dbx.files_list_folder('').entries
    files = [entry.name for entry in entries]
    if files:
        await interaction.response.send_message('\n'.join(files))
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message('No recordings found.')

@tree.command(name="delete_recording", description="Delete a recording")
async def delete_recording(interaction: discord.Interaction, file_name: str):
    dbx.files_delete(f'/{file_name}')
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Deleted {file_name} from Dropbox')

bot.run(TOKEN)

This did not work. Can anyone guide me in the right direction & tell me which library to use to record audio?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
